# Fedora cloud image does not boot fully

Tags: fedora, boot, virtualbox, cloud

I downloaded

https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/31/Cloud/x86_64/images/Fedora-Cloud-Base-31-1.9.x86_64.raw.xz

set root password and created a .vmdk disk image out of that. I created a new VM in VirtualBox and started. On booting the last message was

```
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

and the system stuck. I was somehow able to log in as root but the system was very slow. I was able to invoke dnf and it *did* connect to the Internet.

What could cause this? On any boot it stops here.

Comment: Curious about the image, I converted it to VMDK, created a default VirtualBox VM, and booted.  It sat for several minutes at the "link becomes ready" message but then later cleared the screen and presented a login prompt.

Comment: For you case I would recommend Vagrant/VBox , it is prepared for same virtualization platform. https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/31/Cloud/x86_64/images/Fedora-Cloud-Base-Vagrant-31-1.9.x86_64.vagrant-virtualbox.box  . For troubleshoot, check using `systemd-analyze` ref : https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-analyze.html